# MVC 5 Password Compare always validating

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, data-annotations

I'm new to MVC 5 and my problem is that every time I tried entering the same password in the Confirm Password field, it always fires the validation message `[Compare]`. Is this a common problem ?

Here's my code in Model:

```
[Required]
[StringLength(MaxUserNameLength)]
[Display(Name = "Username")]
public virtual string UserName { get; set; }

[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[StringLength(MaxPasswordLength)]
public virtual string Password { get; set; }

[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[Display(Name = "Confirm Password")]
[Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Doesn't Match")]
public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
```

and here is my code in the View

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control required" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control required" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you also show the action to which you are submitting the form?

Comment: There are two CompareAttribute classes - do you know which one you are using?

Comment: @TiesonT. dont they both work the same?

Comment: @Usman validation is firing after i focus out of the compare password

Comment: @TiesonT. whats the other compareAttribute class?

Comment: i think the client side validation works that way

Comment: They are in different namespaces. System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.CompareAttribute and System.Web.Mvc.CompareAttribute. I'd have to check the source code, but I seem to remember the latter has some issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
@model FailTracker.Models.LoginUser //your model

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Test";
}
```

@using (Html.BeginForm())
   {

```
// your  view code goes here 

<div class="form-group">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
</div>

}
```

This is working fine. I didnt see any problem with the code.